# Are there any way or place to know how to build WDM in VS 2013?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2013, driver, wdm, rootkit

I have learned about the rootkit
Then, I tried to practice example codes,
but, I can't build a wdm driver(only can KMDF)
So, I've searched so many websites but that documents was out-dated

Can you tell me the way or some good place to learn with VS 2013??

(Or, good examples of rootkit tutorial with KMDF)

Comment: exactly i want is, I want to test a kernel-mode rootkit code. so i should write codes and build it. but i can't build properly and can't find good examples for vs 2013, only old examples and WDF projects. I want wdm build tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure as to **exactly** what you're asking for, but try Microsoft Virtual Academy, as they have hundreds of online (free and downloadable) courses on programming or their technology in general.

And to be specific, there are at least 10-12 courses on different frameworks including WDM. I strongly suggest you begin there.

Only problem is knowing how to find the course specifically, as their names can sometimes be misleading, so just read the introduction and the name of each module to see if that's the course for you. Good luck!

MVA: http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/

Comment: Thanks for answer. I did search the cources for that, but i can't find any cources to fit me. Can you suggest the keyword or the way you did?